# Playing YouTube videos on flutter app with ads

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, youtube-api, flutter-dependencies

I want to implement a code based on viewing YouTube videos. I can implement video player with [flutter_youtube_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) plugin however it blocks or doesn't show ads on video that can be seen if opens through YouTube. What approach would be applied in this case? Is it possible to show ads over applications?

Thanks for your help.

```
lass _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  late TextEditingController _idController;
  late TextEditingController _seekToController;

  late PlayerState _playerState;
  late YoutubeMetaData _videoMetaData;
  double _volume = 100;
  bool _muted = false;
  bool _isPlayerReady = false;

  final List<String> _ids = [
    'ynSqKLeGRW8',
    'gQDByCdjUXw',
    'iLnmTe5Q2Qw',
    '_WoCV4c6XOE',
    'KmzdUe0RSJo',
    '6jZDSSZZxjQ',
    'p2lYr3vM_1w',
    '7QUtEmBT_-w',
    '34_PXCzGw1M',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(

      initialVideoId: _ids.first,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        disableDragSeek: false,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        forceHD: false,
        enableCaption: true,

      ),
    )..addListener(listener);
    _idController = TextEditingController();
    _seekToController = TextEditingController();
    _videoMetaData = const YoutubeMetaData();
    _playerState = PlayerState.unknown;
  }

  void listener() {
    if (_isPlayerReady && mounted && !_controller.value.isFullScreen) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = _controller.value.playerState;
        _videoMetaData = _controller.metadata;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // Pauses video while navigating to next page.
    _controller.pause();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _idController.dispose();
    _seekToController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
  
        child: YoutubePlayer(
          
          controller: _controller,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

Comment: I want to make the same with you. Is it possible?